# Crystal Reports Shared Variable in Chart

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a report that is using a Shared StringVar in the details section. I need to find a way to then use this StringVar in a Chart, but when I open up Chart Expert it is not available to print. My end goal is to use SharedEQ variable as the grouping for my chart data. Any help to get this variable to show in a chart would be greatly appreciated!

Below is some more details on my formulas:

```
In Sub Report (in sub report group footer, sub report inserted in main 
report DetailsA: 
whileprintingrecords;
shared stringvar SharedEQ := {@EQ name}

In Main Report (located in detailsB): 
whileprintingrecords;
shared stringvar SharedEq;
SharedEq

In Main Report (to reset variable,located in detailsB): 
shared stringvar SharedEQ := "";
```

Comment: If you create a formula that returns SharedEQ, would it be available in Chart Expert? If so, maybe it is the solution.

Comment: I've tried a basic formula called ShowVariable which was just {SharedEq}. Would you set up the formula differently?

Comment: I would write it with two lines: shared stringvar SharedEQ; SharedEQ; The first line tells that you are acessing a shared var. The second line returns its value.

Comment: where is chart placed in design?

Comment: The Chart would go in the Group footer ideally, the group would be the shared Var

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is due to the Shared Variable being a print-time formula.  Since it is a variable that does not have a value until after the sub-report has printed, its not available for use in a Chart in your main report.

https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-10998

There is a workaround where you can place the chart in a sub-report though.  To use this effectively, you may need to create additional Shared Variables to pass all of the values to the sub-report where your chart will print.

Comment: Should I be placing the chart in the Orignal subreport that holds my shared variable?

Comment: The answer to that question depends on the structure of the report.  Will that subreport only print once, or will it repeat multiple times when the report is printed?  If it repeats, then that will cause the chart to repeat as well.  If this isn't what you desire, then you will need a second subreport.  If it only prints once though, and the location this subreport prints, relative the main report, is an appropriate location to print the chart, then that shouldn't be an issue.